# Pot Power calculations is a searching process to determine the peak power (75- 99 % of linear pot). Why is this not normally discussed?

Tags: power, potentiometer

[image]

Here are the math relationships involved.  The maximum theoretical power requires a searching process.  It is important because the user may park the pot in that position.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the actual question here? It's *generally* the case that circuits that can exist in a variety of states have a variety of power dissipation levels and all states need to be considered. Furthermore, 6% off the endpoint values isn't even that remarkable of a difference, given that it's easy enough to buy a pot that's rated for 50%, 100% over the power requirement, or doesn't even participate in the power chain (e.g. a pot as a feedback element) thus allowing its power dissipation to be well below its limit.

Comment: **Why is this not normally discussed?**  ( it's just another one in a million questions) what's normal? Did you find the math to prove your measurements for Pmax (pot) were correct? Are they correct?

Comment: Can you use Thevenin Equivalent voltage Veq and Req to find Pmax for a ratio = α  for pot? with R1=R2  ( or in your case α = R2/(R1+R2 ) and (R1+R2)=R3  *you gotta love math right?*

Comment: Because pots are usually used for low power signals and so far from their ratings it's not usually worth the effort.

Answer (score 6):

It's not normally that much of a consideration. Many pots are used as potentiometers (as opposed to rheostats) with negligible wiper current and/or used way, way below their rated dissipation as trimmers.

The pot dissipation rating is for the entire element, and any situation that exposes part of the element to a large proportion of the dissipation the entire element is rated for would best be derated considerably (and attention paid to any wiper current rating the manufacturer cares to share).

It does make a nice homework problem because it allows the student to apply simple calculus but has little practical value.

The greatest power dissipation per unit length of the element occurs as the wiper nears terminal 1. The greatest spot temperature rise on the element occurs with the wiper also near the maximum, depending on pot construction. It is the **concentration** of power dissipation that can cause unexpected damage. Ref. **Potentiometer Handbook** ISBN 0-07-006690-6

Answer (score 1):

The pot power rating determines the maximum current that the pot can handle in any portion of its track.

If the 2 kΩ pot in your diagram has a power rating of 200 mW then the maximum current the track can handle is \$ I = \sqrt {\frac P R } = 10 \, \mathrm {mA} \$.

Maximum current in your circuit will occur when the pot is closest to the top. You only need to check the current at that point doesn't exceed the pot's maximum current. If you draw another graph showing current as a function of pot rotation this should become clear.

Summary: many people make the mistake that the pot's power rating can be handled over a portion of the track. It can't.